# React JS - Separator PublicTheme and PublicTheme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

In the React project, I am creating the admin dashboard and the UI area that users will see.

I couldn't separate the admin theme from the PublicTheme.

When I go to `"/admin/login"` as the URL, I still see the `publicheader` and `publicfooter` in the `PublicTheme` while I should see `adminheader` and `adminfooter`.

I'm using `react-router-dom` v6.

AdminTheme

```
import Header from "../compenents/layout/Admin/Header";
import Footer from "../compenents/layout/Admin/Footer";

const AdminTheme = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default AdminTheme;
```

PublicTheme

```
import Header from "../compenents/layout/Public/Header";
import Footer from "../compenents/layout/Public/Footer";

const PublicTheme = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default PublicTheme;
```

AdminRoute

```
export default function AdminRoute() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="admin/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="admin/posts" element={<Post />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

PublicRoute

```
export default function PublicRoute() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/projects" element={<Project />} />
      <Route path="/blog" element={<Blog />} />
      <Route path="/posts" element={<Post />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<Page404 />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <PublicTheme>
        <main className="container mx-auto px-2 sm:px-4 pt-12">
          <div className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row justify-between gap-x-8 mb-20">
            <PublicRoute />
          </div>
        </main>
      </PublicTheme>

      <AdminTheme>
        <AdminRoute />
      </AdminTheme>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PublicTheme` and the `AdminTheme` are being rendered in the root of the app component. Add some conditions render based on the route.

I would create a LayoutRouter where you will handle the condition based on the route:

```
import { Outlet, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function LayoutRouter() {
  const location = useLocation();

  if (location.pathname.startsWith('/admin')) {
    return <AdminTheme><Outlet /></AdminTheme>;
  }
  return <PublicTheme><Outlet /></PublicTheme>;
}
```

And then in the app.js update it:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<LayoutRouter />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/projects" element={<Project />} />
          <Route path="/blog" element={<Blog />} />
          <Route path="/posts" element={<Post />} />
          <Route path="admin/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="admin/posts" element={<Post />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Page404 />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

***One way is to use conditional rendering :***

**App.js**

```
function App() {

  const location = useLocation() 

  return !location.pathname.includes('/admin') ? (        
      <PublicTheme>
        <main className="container mx-auto px-2 sm:px-4 pt-12">
          <div className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row justify-between gap-x-8 mb-20">
            <PublicRoute />
          </div>
        </main>
      </PublicTheme>
   ) : (
      <AdminTheme>
        <AdminRoute />
      </AdminTheme>
   )        
  );

}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert `AdminTheme` and `PublicTheme` into layout routes. Render the appropriate nested routes into each.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from "../components/layout/Admin/Header";
import Footer from "../components/layout/Admin/Footer";

const AdminTheme = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Outlet />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default AdminTheme;
```

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from "../components/layout/Public/Header";
import Footer from "../components/layout/Public/Footer";

const PublicTheme = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <main className="container mx-auto px-2 sm:px-4 pt-12">
        <div className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row justify-between gap-x-8 mb-20">
          <Outlet />
        </div>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default PublicTheme;
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<PublicTheme />}>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/projects" element={<Project />} />
        <Route path="/blog" element={<Blog />} />
        <Route path="/posts" element={<Post />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Page404 />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/admin" element={<AdminTheme />}>
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="posts" element={<Post />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```